# Exact Same Application Work in One Computer Doesn't Work in the Other

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I and my friend have project files connected to dropbox. So code are the same.

Then, when I execute

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Business" inManagedObjectContext:[BNUtilitiesQuick managedObjectContext]];
```

I got something.
That same code set entity to nil in my friends' computer.

The BadgerNew.xcdatamodeld that's used to create the managedObject already changed. My team have reset the IPhone simulator and deleted the application from the IPhone simulator so that the whole thing is created new again. Doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Not enough information to give a terribly useful answer.

However, *DropBox* is a **horrible** way to share a project.  If you have multiple people working on the same codebase, then you should be using a revision control tool of some kind;  svn and git being the most popular these days.

Grab the source from your friend's computer and drop it on your own. Then diff the two;  `opendiff MySource MyFriendsSource`.  See what differs.    If nothing differs (unlikely), then there is something different in the configuration of your two machines.

Comment: I can assure you the code is exactly the same. What I put always show up there.

Comment: In fact, I connect to his computer, run the project in his computer and it works. I think it has something to do with the fact that the xcdatamodel have indeed changed. However, I have reset the IPhone simulator several times.

Comment: My friend can run the application if he uses some sort of profile. However, if he run the program again, the error changes. Now it says

Comment: Then the error become "The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store". However we have resetted the iPhone simulator several time.

Comment: Sounds like the reset isn't resetting everything;  you have stale data on one machine that isn't present on the other.

Comment: Given that it is the data store that is causing the problem.  Grab the store from the two machines and compare them.  Then compare the models.